# Select pairs of values when searching a DB

Tags: mysql, select, grouping

Ina  simple language translation table, I want to search a lang1<=>lang2 pairs. In my search form 3 fields are available:
  1. Neutral text (entry name)
  2. Text in language1
  3. Text in language2

If any field is ommited, the search should return everything, however **only if filled fields match**. The table looks like this:

```
id | neutral text | language | translation
---+--------------+----------+------------
 0 |       SUBMIT |       en |      Submit
 1 |       SUBMIT |       cs |     Odeslat
 2 |       SUBMIT |       fr |    Démarrer
 3 |          DAY |       fr |        Jour
 4 |       MONDAY |       fr |       Lundi
 5 |       MONDAY |       cs |     Pondělí
```

I find it quite complicated to find out, how to return only matching values, but associate them with their pair language (in one query). I tried to make a condition based on existence of other language:

```
//Executes if only one language value is specified 
SELECT name, lang, content FROM `texty` WHERE name LIKE $neutral_txt AND (content LIKE $l1_val AND lang=$l1 OR lang=$lang2 AND 0 < (SELECT count(*) FROM `texty` WHERE content LIKE $l1_val AND lang=$l1)) GROUP BY name
```

I also tried to add `GROUP BY` statement in hope only values with same `name` will be returned, but current aproach returs all entries in language2 (provided there is at least one entry matching `$l1_val`).
I want the query to return following (using languages `cs` and `fr`):

```
Filled fields: neutral text="SUBMIT"
   ->rows 1,2
Filled fields: translation_fr="Démarrer"
   ->rows 1,2
Filled fields: translation_fr="Jour"
   ->rows 3
```

So, I just want to pair found values with other values with same name. Queries where both or none language are specified work fine for me.

**One more explanation:**
I have a database with above structure - it contains language name, the name of the entry (neutral text) and the value in the language specified. I want to search this database, searching always by 2 different language translations (eg.: "Odeslat", "Demarrer") and the entry name (eg.: "SUBMIT").
But any of the search requirements can be ommited. I want the search to return also all entries for which the other language has matched. As in above examples:

User searches for translation containing "Démarrer" in language 'fr' and the other language is 'cs'. So the row 2 is returned - it contains the query. But also, I wish to return row 1, so that I can display the czech version of "Démarrer".
This queries should serve in purpose of comparing translations.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you require. The data you supply does not relate to the query or the output.We require at least the database schema and expected result.

Comment: I tried to explain it further. I'm sorry, but what I want is not actually simple I guess - however I also believe its not pointless. I need to have a search in translation table to allow users compare translations in two different languages.